# which one is best for chat applicaiton? socket programming vs rmi?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, rmi

I want to create a chat application which is client/server based. 
What will be the best? Using sockets or by using rmi?

PS: Is it possible to create chat application by using rmi?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html.

Comment: Please reformulate the question into something less subjective.

Comment: But which is best? I want it to handle multiple clients at the same time (like chatroom)!

Comment: if your server and client application will be made in Java, I recommend using RMI, if the client (or mabye another clients) will be build in another language like C, C++ or C#, use socket orientation

Comment: What is your target network? LAN? Internet? Clients behind proxies/ firewalls/ gateways?

Comment: Then you'll be interested in [this example](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RMI is a technology that works ontop of sockets. It's comparing apples to oranges. Sockets are the low-level stuff that handles the network communication, while RMI is a protocol that sits ontop of sockets in order to make it possible to invoke java methods on remote JVMs.

Answer (score 2):

In Socket programming, you have to handle exactly which sockets/port are being and is the low level communication used with a relevant protocol to handle communication - either been TCP or UDP, for client/server communication. You also handle all the passing messages travelling between client and server.

You can communicate to a socket application using any programming language And so a socket program written in Java can accept calls from Python, C/C++, Haskel etc.

RMI on the other hand is build on top of sockets, it hides much of the network specific code, you don't have to worry about specific ports yet can still select one if you want. RMI handles the message passing between client and server. RMI is for communication betwwen Java client/server applications.

Comment: Thank you! In what protocol does rmi message communicate? and what is stub?